# subfigures using subfloat- how to change the size of numbering

Tags: floats, subfloats, labels

I am using the following code to create subfigures.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{scrextend}
 \usepackage{floatrow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[label font=bf]{subfig}
 \floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
  \begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
 \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{example-image-a}}\\ 
 \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{example-image-b}}
 \label{example}
\vspace{-0.7ex} 
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to change the size of figure numbers (a) and (b) keeping the size of figure fixed? They are currently smaller than my preferred size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to set it to `\normalsize`, following the `caption` syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{scrextend}
 \usepackage{floatrow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[label font={bf, normalsize}]{subfig}
 \floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

  \begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
 \begin{figure}[!htb]
 \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{example-image-a}}\\
 \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 3in]{example-image-b}}
 \label{example}
\vspace{-0.7ex}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]